# Open file by passing its path works on Linux but doesn't on windows

Tags: linux, windows, go

I made a little program for my job that take a file open it and retrieve some informations I need and put them in 2 new files.

I wrote the code on my machine and it works as expected but I'm on Ubuntu and I need to use this tool at work on a windows and it crash.

```
The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.check(...)
        C:/Users/GADC/go/Natstar-util/listerDll/main.go:80
main.main()
        C:/Users/GADC/go/Natstar-util/listerDll/main.go:18 +0x8d5
exit status 2
```

Here's my code:

```
func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Entrez le chemin de votre export: ")

    filepath, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    check(err)

    file, err := os.Open(strings.Split(filepath,"\n")[0])
    check(err)

    defer file.Close()
}


func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}
```

If someone have an idea to help me, it would be great.
Thanks :)

[EDIT] here just the piece of buggy code.

Comment: Line 18 is after `remoteDllFile, err:= os.Create("./ListeDllServeur.txt")` Does this function accept `/` as path delimiter on Windows? Try if it helps when you  omit `./`, i.e. `os.Create("ListeDllServeur.txt")`. (Both `ListeDllServeur.txt` and `./ListeDllServeur.txt` specify the same file.)

Comment: @Bodo, line 18 is the  `check(err)` call following `os.Open(strings.Split(filepath,"\n")[0])`, which lines up with `panic(e)` call on line 80 in the traceback. `Open` is passed an invalid filename. Maybe the line ending that's read from stdin is `"\r\n"` instead of `"\n"`. ASCII control characters such as CR are reserved in Microsoft's filesystems.

Comment: Please provide the minimum code snippet which show the problem.

Comment: @volker here it is.

Comment: @Bodo If I replace filepath by the name of my file, it read the file and create the two others, everything works. But I want to be able to provide the filename (or path) during execution.

Comment: @G.D You should make sure that problem description, output and code match. At the time when I wrote the comment, line 17 was exactly as I wrote, not `os.Open(strings.Split(filepath,"\n")[0])`. In this case I would have recommended to print the intermediate result of `strings.Split()` before using it as input for `os.Open()`. You could also pass the file name (or a string with other relevant data) to function `check` to be printed in an error case. To see errors like a trailing `\r`, `\n` or space I suggest to surround the value with printable characters when printing, e.g. `"..."` or `<...>`.

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLVED]

@eryksun was right. The problem was I split my path on '\n' instead of "\r\n".

Now it's working.

Thanks to all :)